# Firebase Test Lab, Robo Testing creating issue.

Tags: android, testing, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I have developed an android application, and this app is now in testing phase. I have tested this on physical devices as well as on Genymotion, with different combinations of devices and API , and the app is working fine.  For Robo testing, I am using Firebase Test Lab. On virtual device having API level greater than 23, I am getting below error

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: local-1
 Process: com.google.android.videos, PID: 7122
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.accounts.Account.type' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1689)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
    at com.android.vending.contentfilters.IContentFiltersService$Stub$Proxy.getContentFiltersAndIntent(SourceFile:139)
    at com.google.android.videos.service.contentfiltering.ContentFiltersManager$1$2.get(SourceFile:484)
    at com.google.android.videos.service.contentfiltering.ContentFiltersManager$1$2.get(SourceFile:478)
    at com.google.android.videos.utils.async.SupplyToReceiverRunnable.run(SourceFile:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at com.google.android.videos.utils.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(SourceFile:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I am unable to figure out reason for this, will you please suggest me possible causes for this. Thanks

Comment: This error occurs when you are referring to an object which isn't initialized. For example if you have a textview which you haven't `findViewById` and you try to `.setText` this error will occur. Share the code which triggers this error so we can help you. I don't think this error could happen due to API but in a specific case you may not have covered until now.

Comment: Thanks @Antonis for your response. If API level not creating problem then why its not happening on API level 19 and below. Unfortunately, this exception is not pointing to any specific piece of snippet in my code. And complete application code can't be share. One question, my app require google service to work. Is it possibility that virtual devices don't have google play services installed on them

Comment: Not sure but i believe yes, for example Genymotion emulators doesn't support Google Play Services by default. It would be a good question towards  the Firebase Test Lab to be sure if Googe Play Services are running.

Answer (score 1):

You may have found an issue with our virtual devices.

Please use the submit a bug page on https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/ to get the information to the right people.

Comment: Other reviewers: I really don't think that this is a link-only answer because it has context, explains what the page is for, and not to mention is from someone in an official capacity. I'm hesitant to delete this but your opinion may differ.

Comment: @Tony Kai I have reported this issue.